# Show all branches merged to Master between 2 dates - Git

Tags: git, git-log

With git log I can use --since and --until to show data between 2 dates. 
And with git branch -r I can extract all the remote branches.

How would I show all branches merged to master between 2 dates?

```
git log --since "DEC 1 2019" --until "JAN 1 2020" --pretty=format:"%h %an %ad"
```

This returns all commits between 2 dates but I'd like to return the branch names between these 2 dates that were merged to master?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would the option `--merges` do the job for you?

Comment: It would.  Thanks very much - exactly what I needed.  Is there an easy way to extract the date and message? I dont need to see the merge commit ref, author but just the date and message?

Comment: Ah never mind - I think the below will do. Thanks again - you can post answer and I'll mark as correct. 

git log --since "DEC 1 2019" --until "JAN 1 2020" --merges --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, commuting. Anyway, can you try and see if `--date=iso` is gonna make things better.

Comment: It did! Thanks very much.

Comment: I'm glad it did :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with the `--merges` and the `--date` flags for `git log`. So it will look like:

```
git log --merges --date=iso --since "DEC 1 2019" --until "JAN 1 2020" --pretty=format:"%h %an %ad"
```