# Git : how to list all remote branches which ve been merged to master from a specific date / sorted by date

Tags: git

I want to list all remote features branches which have been already merged to my "master" branch, ordered by date or sorted by chronological date of merge.

I'm using this command, to get the merged branches, but still cannot get the sort or the list ordered by date of merge:

```
git branch -r --merged master | grep "origin/"
```

Suggesstions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show all branches merged to Master between 2 dates - Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59667932/show-all-branches-merged-to-master-between-2-dates-git)

Answer (score 1):

```
git for-each-ref --merged=master --sort=authordate refs/remotes/
```

See [the docs for `git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref).

Pattern `refs/remotes/` means "list only remote branches".